# nginx Request line too large

Tags: nginx, http, web, 400

I'm getting the error:

```
Bad Request
Request Line is too large (6060 > 4094)
```

When I access the a specific url on my server like this:

```
/api/categorize?packages=package1,package2,...packageN
```

On nginx.conf I have:

```
large_client_header_buffers 8 16k;

client_header_buffer_size 8k;
```

I can't find documentation on that specific issue, the docs for large_client_header_buffers mention 400 Bad request, but changing "large_client_header_buffers" from 4 8k; or 8 8k; or 8 16; didn't fix the problem.

Comment: are you using nginx only or is it a frontend for gunicorn? because it seems this error comes from gunicorn: https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/symbols/python/gunicorn/http/errors/LimitRequestLine

Comment: @mauro.stettler It is a frontend for gunicorn. How would I increase the URL length on gunicorn, then?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This error seems to come from a Gunicorn backend, not from Nginx. You can change it's limit by passing the parameter `--limit-request-line` or set `limit_request_line`.

You can see a description [here](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html?highlight=limit_request_line#limit-request-line).

Comment: This is exactly what I neded.